# Start jquery function when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drplayer plugin on this page http://corkparties.com/christmas-parties-cork.html
It allows me to play songs one after the other in a playlist. It has functions for stop resume  etc in this file http://www.corkparties.com/js/drplayer.js

How do i get the plugin to start playing the first song when i load the page. I dont want a user to have to click the play button.

I have tried this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = play;
    </script>
```

But this doesnt work. Does any body know a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work in the console:

```
$('.btn.play').eq(0).trigger('click'); // using .eq(0) to get the first one
```

Wrap it in a `document.ready` call to have it work on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn.play').eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```